# How to export csv file with specific name?

Tags: c#

I want to export csv file from the database by specific names, such as the data of patient contains "Ward name" field as "GENERAL WARD (FEMALE)" then the gererated file name must be "GENF.csv ". I tried with switch-case but it is not working. If there are any changes please edit.

Thanks.

**Here is the code:**

```
//Function declares methods to export
public void ExportAll() {
    try {
        int i = 0;
        for (int icount = 0; icount <= 400; icount++) {
            object o = saiNathHospitalDataSet.Tables["PatientTable"].Rows[i]["WARD NAME"];
            object obj = saiNathHospitalDataSet.Tables["PatientTable"].Rows[i]["PTNAME"];

            int swichexpression = 9;
            object a = "GENERAL WARD (FEMALE)";
            object b = "GENERAL WARD (MALE)";
            object c = "RECOVERY";
            object d = "SEMI DELUXE 02";
            object e = "SEMI DELUXE 05";
            object f = "SEMI DELUXE 06";
            object g = "ICU";
            object h = "SEMI SPECIAL 03";
            object j = "SEMI SPECIAL 01";

            switch (swichexpression) {
                case 1:
                if (o == a) { 
                    // o = "GENF";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] =" + o + "", "GENF.csv");
                }
                break;
                case 2:
                if (o == b) { 
                    // o = "GENM";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] =" + o + "", "GENM.csv");
                }
                break;
                case 3:
                if (o == c) {
                    //o = "REC";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] ="  + o + "", "REC.csv");
                }
                break;
                case 4:
                if (o == d) { 
                    // o = "SDELX02";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] =" + o + "", "SDELX02.csv");
                }
                break;
                case 5:
                if (o == e) { 
                    // o = "SDELX05";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] =" + o + "", "SDELX05.csv");
                }
                break;
                case 6:
                if (o == f) { 
                    // o = "SDELX06";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] =" + o + "", "SDELX06.csv");
                }
                break;
                case 7:
                if (o == g) { 
                    //o = "ICU";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] =" + o + "", "ICU.csv");
                }
                break;
                case 8:
                if (o == h) { 
                    //o = "SSPEC03";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] =" + o + "", "SSPEC03.csv");
                }
                break;
                case 9:
                if (o == j) {
                    //string z = "SSPEC01";
                    DataExport("select * from PatientTable where [WARD NAME] =" + o + "", "SSPEC01.csv");
                }
                break;
            }
            //DataExport("select * from PatientTable", "" + s + ".csv");
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch {

    }
}
```

**Edited::Data Export Method,**

```
  public void DataExport(string SelectQuery, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dt = new DataTable())
            {
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectQuery, con))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    var header = String.Join(
                        ",",
                        dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(dc => dc.ColumnName));

                    var rows =
                        from dr in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                        select String.Join(
                            ",",
                            from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                            let t1 = Convert.IsDBNull(dr[dc]) ? "" : dr[dc].ToString()
                            let t2 = t1.Contains(",") ? String.Format("\"{0}\"", t1) : t1
                            select t2);

                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(txtreceive.Text + "\\" + fileName))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(header);
                        foreach (var row in rows)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(row);
                        }
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: What is `DataExport`? Where should it get the file name from?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and fix your variable names, they're horrible. Give `string` variables a static type of what they are - `string`s. Handle possible exceptions apropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch case is incorrect, right now you're making a mix of switch case and if statements, but your switch case will always go to case 9 and you don't actually need a switch case on integers. You need to change it to something like this:

```
    string o = saiNathHospitalDataSet.Tables["PatientTable"].Rows[i]["WARD NAME"];

    const string a = "GENERAL WARD (FEMALE)";
    const string b = "GENERAL WARD (MALE)";
    const string c = "RECOVERY";
    const string d = "SEMI DELUXE 02";
    const string e = "SEMI DELUXE 05";
    const string f = "SEMI DELUXE 06";
    const string g = "ICU";
    const string h = "SEMI SPECIAL 03";
    const string j = "SEMI SPECIAL 01";

    switch (o)
    {
        case (a):
            //Do something
            break;
        case (b):
            //Do something
            break;
        default:
            //Do something
            break;
    }
```

Edit: If you want to export a file per patient for each of your wards, you will have to change your foreach loop of your export method to something like this:

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(txtreceive.Text + "\\" + "Some variable to identify different patients" + filename))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(header);
        sw.WriteLine(row);
    }
}
```

Assuming each row represents a patient, you need to create a file per row.

Comment: Can you post the DataExport method in your question?